# Misleading error message after unhandled exception in wsadmin script

Tags: python, websphere, jython, wsadmin, jacl

I'm developing an automation framework and I've experienced strange behavior of `wsadmin` tool. The problem is reproducible in WAS 6.1, 7.0 and 8.0 (I haven't tried with was 8.5).

I'm wondering if this is a bug in wsadmin (quite strange that nobody noticed it yet, probably since WAS 5!)...

The example scripts can be safely executed against any WAS environment without doing any harm.

```py
try:
    # this line throws WAS exception
    AdminConfig.list('NonExistentType')
except:
    # exception is being handled
    print 'Handled wsadmin exception'
print 'Raising another exception'
# eventually the script throws a non-WAS exception
x = 1/0
```

If I understand correctly, the above script fails on zero-division. But `wsadmin` output is a bit confusing:

```
Handled wsadmin exception
Raising another exception
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "ex.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidConfigDataTypeException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidConfigDataTypeException: ADMG0007E: The configuration data type NonExistentType is not valid.
```

What's really interesting, Jacl seems to have the same problem:

```tcl
if [catch { puts [$AdminConfig list NonExistentType] } result] {
    puts "Handled wsadmin exception"
}
puts "Raising another exception"
set x [expr 1 / 0]
```

`wsadmin` also does not print any information about the actual exception which terminated the script:

```
Handled wsadmin exception
Raising another exception
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "ex.jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidConfigDataTypeException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidConfigDataTypeException: ADMG0007E: The configuration data type NonExistentType is not valid.
```

After changing both scripts slightly (to avoid throwing WAS exception), the output of both scripts is correct.

```py
try:
    # this line does not throw any exception
    AdminConfig.list('Cell')
except:
    # exception is being handled
    print 'Handled wsadmin exception'
print 'Raising another exception'
# eventually the script throws a non-WAS exception
x = 1/0
```

If the script doesn't throw/handle WAS exception, the output looks as expected:

```
Raising another exception
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "ex1.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython:
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in ?
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo
```

Same with Jacl:

```tcl
if [catch { puts [$AdminConfig list Cell] } result] {
    puts "Handled wsadmin exception"
}
puts "Raising another exception"
set x [expr 1 / 0]
```

`wsadmin` outputs the following, which again is quite expected:

```
wdrCell(cells/wdrCell|cell.xml#Cell_1)
Raising another exception
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "ex1.jacl"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: error while eval'ing Jacl expression:
divide by zero
    while executing
"expr 1 / 0"
    invoked from within
"set x [expr 1 / 0]"
```

I have to confess a bit: the reason why I'm asking this question is that I actually reported the problem to WebSphere Support. I'm not fully satisfied with their replies though. Wsadmin/Jython/Jacl/Python/Tcl experts: what's your opinion on that?

Am I doing something wrong?

Is it a bug in `wsadmin`?

Is it expected behavior???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be fixed in upcoming FixPacks for WSAS 6.1, 7.0, 8.0 and 8.5.

IBM Support was a bit concerned about breaking compatibility with previous implementations (well, it's arguable, but some scripts may rely on this bug), therefore the proper behavior needs to be explicitly enabled using `com.ibm.ws.scripting.exceptionPropagation=thrown` JVM property.

I'm aware of two ways of passing this property to wsadmin's JVM:

- `javaOption` environment variable
- `javaoption` option

The environment variable way:

```
export javaOption=-Dcom.ibm.ws.scripting.exceptionPropagation=thrown
./wsadmin.sh -lang jython -f script.py
```

The command-line option way:

```
./wsadmin.sh -javaoption -Dcom.ibm.ws.scripting.exceptionPropagation=thrown-lang jython -f script.py
```

The fix solves the problem for both Jython and Jacl.

Link to official document: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM80400